# Simulating Menu button?

Tags: windows, keyboard, shortcuts, context-menu

I'm using an IBM ThinkPad keyboard, the one with TrackPoint and without any Windows keys. Since Win-keys tend to be quiet useful, I've remapped left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to work as <kbd>Win</kbd> button, <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to be my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the only button I'm missing now is the <kbd>Menu</kbd> button to show context menus.

Now, I know a couple of "emulation" shortcuts: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> for application menu for example. Any such shortcut for the <kbd>Menu</kbd> button?

Comment: I assume when you say "menu button" you're talking about the right-click keyboard key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Shift + F10** should do the job for you.

Comment: +1 for being faster by 18secs.

Comment: Wow! It only shows me 1 second :)

Answer (score 3):

Shift-F10 - there ya go.

Comment: Apparently I was 1 second faster :)

Comment: Darn! If only I had that i7-950, 32GB RAM, and that T3 connection I was dreaming of just last week...

Comment: Like I do :)? My trusty Pentium 4 with 1.25 GB of RAM is the best, when it's not hanging :).

Comment: Yea .., I'd spend $1000 on hardware just to get few more SU points.